# Apache Ignite: How to automatically remove cache objects upon session expiration?

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

Apache Ignite: cache objects not expire

Hello,

I’m using Apache Ignite 2.14.0.

WebSessionFilter removes the Primary cache but remains Backup when the session is expired,

If the cache’s `atomicityMode` is set to `TRANSACTIONAL`.

How can I set up a cache to be removed when it is expired?

Comment: Could you please elaborate about how you knew that an entry hadn't expired?

Comment: I saw cache objects with ignitevisorcmd.sh. 
cache -a command shows Primary object disappears when it expires, but the Backup is not.